# ETS multiplicative trend model written in state space form

Tags: time-series, forecasting, state-space

I have an ETS(M,Md,N) model and would like to write it in state space form:

yt=w(x{t-1})+r(x{t-1})ɛt
xt=f(x{t-1})+g(x{t-1})ɛt

For additive trend, the state vector xt=(lt,bt)'. But I have no idea how to write the state vector xt for multiplicative trend.

Can anyone help please:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state vector is exactly the same in the multiplicative case as in the additive case. All the equations are given here: https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/7

For the ETS(M,Md,N) model,

[image]

Comment: I want to convert the above three equations into the form y_t and x_t, same form as equations 2.12a and 2.12b in your book <<Forecasting with exponential smoothing>>. In your book, you give examples for additive trend (state vector multiplied by matrix). But if I use the same vector (l_t, b_t)' multiplied by a matrix, l_t and b_t would be added together.

Comment: The functions are not linear. I've updated my answer to give more of the details.